# Assign tableviewcontroller to uiview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, segue

I want to assign tableviewcontroller object to a uiview(which is really just a view container).
I don't want to use the embed segue to accomplish this. This is because I don't want all my views to come back to the same tableviewcontroller object.

What is the correct way of going about this?
Any help would be of great help
Thanks in advance

Comment: 'Assign a controller to a view'? What do you mean?

Comment: And this: "This is because I don't want all my views to come back to the same tableviewcontroller object." What does that mean? You need to clarify your question.